# why do my elements = 0 after inputting a number into array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to learn arrays and I cannot understand why after inputting all my arrays when I get it to show in my text box it says that they are all 0 ?

Here is my code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int[] a = new int[10]; //global int!!!

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn_Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //all elements show as 0 but why ??? come back to this later tonight!


        string input;

        for (int place = 0; place < 10; place++)
        {
             input = null;

             My_Dialogs.InputBox("User Input Request!", "Please enter a number to be stored in element " + place + " : ", ref input);
    Int32.TryParse(input, out a[place]);

        }
    }

    private void btn_display_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int place = 0; place < 10; place++)
             textBox1.AppendText("Element" + place + " of the array contains " + a[place] + "\n");
    }

    private void btn_quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Here is the mydialogs code

```
class My_Dialogs
{
    public static string InputBox(string promptText)
    {
        string default_value = "";

        return InputBox("", promptText, ref default_value);
    }
    public static string InputBox(string title, string promptText)
    {
        string default_value = "";

        return InputBox(title, promptText, ref default_value);
    }
    public static string InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        Label label = new Label();
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        Button buttonOk = new Button();
        Button buttonCancel = new Button();

        form.Text = title;
        label.Text = promptText;
        textBox.Text = value;

        buttonOk.Text = "OK";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        label.AutoSize = true;
        textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });
        form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.MinimizeBox = false;
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
        form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
        return textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: You didn't check if to conversion succeeds. Does it? Debug the code and see what happens.

Comment: Seems like `input` cannot be parsed to an integer. Set a breakpoint at `Int32.TryParse()` and evaluate the content of input.

Comment: does your code compile? i think you cant use `out` modifier with indexer `a[place]`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it's possible. I had the same thought so I tested it.

Comment: was just about to say it does work but it is shown as they all = 0

Comment: Check the result of `Int32.TryParse()`. It's `true` if the operation is successful, `false` otherwise.  `if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out a[place])) textBox1.AppendText("No valid input");`

Comment: `public static string InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)` returns a string but is not re-setting the value parameter. in fact, it's not clear why you even use a ref parameter if you are returning the string anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you got this code for the inputbox from your instructor? It never assigns the inserted text to `value` thus your `input` variable will always be null. You should either insert

```
value = textBox.Text;
```

in your InputBox code

or use

```
input = My_Dialogs.InputBox("User Input Request!", "Please enter a number to be stored in element " + place + " : ");
```

Furthermore you should check the result of `TryParse` if the conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
You need to add the following to your MyDialog class right before the return statement:

`value = textBox.Text;`

This works just fine for me: (assuming the input is in fact an int.)

Without knowing whats in `My_Dialogs.InputBox` Its hard to tell what the problem is.  What is the value of input immediately following the dialog box?

```
class Program
    {
        private static int[] a = new int[10]; //global int!!!
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int place = 0; place < a.Length; place++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to be stored in element " + place + " : ");
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                Int32.TryParse(input, out a[place]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: setting the value happens in the line `Int32.TryParse(input, out a[place]);`

Comment: @CharlesMager See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T8dzsr) which shows that setting an arrayelement in an out variable works

Comment: My_Dialogs.InputBox is what i was given by my tutor to use as an input box

Comment: You need to set a break point and see what the value of input is before you call TryParse. Without seeing the code for the dialog box there isnt much else any of us can do.

Comment: like someone said above - the dialog box never returns a value. Therefore you'll never input a value into the array.